# Android lint producing different results when run in Android Studo vs. Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, lint

When I run lint "in" Android Studio (Analyze -> Inspect Code) I see a report of many issues in my application.  However, when I run `gradlew lint` I am told no issues exist!

My `lintOptions` section in my `app.gradle` file is:

```
lintOptions {
    warningsAsErrors true
    abortOnError true
    xmlReport false
    htmlOutput project.file('build/reports/lint/lint-report.html')
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Why would there be zero issues found when using the `gradlew lint` command?

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it helped! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I summed up some of my research about lint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42761329/context-of-lint-xml-and-inspection-profile).

Basically `gradlew lint` is using lint.xml with a ruleset R.
Android Studio Analyze using is using R from lint.xml **as well as** ruleset P from the inspection profile.

Therefore it is possible for a rule in P to trigger in Analyze but not in `gradlew lint`!

Comment: It's been a while and I apologize, but thank you for the investigation work you did.  You are totally correct - Android Studio Analyze does a lot more than just Lint checking and the rulesets/tools running in both cases are not the same.