# Importing lint.xm for inspection in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, lint

Is there a way to use the lint.xml defined in the gradle file when we run code inspection in Android Studio?

I notice when i run lint via gradle the lint.xml is used and when running code inspection in Android Studio the studio inspection profile is used

According to the thread below the lint.xml can be imported via the manage button but it only allows me to choose inspection profiles and not lint.xml:
[Context of lint.xml and inspection profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42761329/context-of-lint-xml-and-inspection-profile)

Anyone managed to use the lint.xml while using the Android Studio inspect code?

Comment: For better understanding have look [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint)

Comment: @PastAndSalmon I have the same concern now. Did u  find a way to use lint.xml when running code inspection?